# Python Property alias to a member variable attribute

Tags: python, properties, python-2.x

I want to create a class property (named "v") which has value of "x.val"
where  x is a attribute value of class.

I designed as below code... But it doesn't work when i assign new value to property "v",
the value of "x.val" is not change.

1. at first, i create a new object PClass, at that time, the v property and "x.val" have same value is 1 which is value of "x.val"
2. I assign a new value 9999 to "v". The expected is value of "v.val" will change to 9999
   But it not. The value of "v" changed to 9999 but "v.val" still is 1.
   Moreover, it look like function "setv" is never reached.

I don't know why this case happen ? Any ideal, please let me know!

THanks for all!

```
class ValClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 1
        self.var = 2

    def pr(self):
        print "==== PR ===="
        print self.val #1
        print self.var #2   


class PClass:
    x = ValClass()
    y = '1'

    def getv(self):
        return self.x.val

    def setv(self, val):
        self.x.val = val

    def delv(self):
        del self.x.val

    v = property(getv, setv, delv)

    def solv(self):
        print self.v #9999
        self.x.pr()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = PClass()
    p.v = 9999
    print p.v
    p.solv()
```

Comment: Be careful, `p.x` is *shared* between instances. Create a new instance of `ValClass()` in `__init__` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`setv` is not called, change `class PClass:` to `class PClass(object):` to make *PClass* a subclass of *object*

Comment: The difference is that of a old-style class vs. a new-style class. Only new-style classes support the descriptor protocol required to make `property` work.

Answer (score 2):

`property` can only be used on new-style classes. If your class does not inherit from `object`, it cannot implement properties!

```
class PClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = ValClass() # if you don't do this, all PClass objects will share an x
        self.y = 1

    @property
    def v(self):
        return self.x.val
    @v.setter
    def v(self, val):
        self.x.val = val
    @v.deleter
    def v(self):
        del self.x.val

    def solv(self):
        print self.v #9999
        self.x.pr()
```